# Trying to get Pyramid running under Apache + mod_wsgi but it's failing

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I've got Apache2 running with mod_wsgi installed. I've confirmed that mod_wsgi actually works by following [this](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/mod_wsgi+and+workingenv.py#id4).

The problem comes when I try to get Pyramid running. I get an Internal Server Error and my Apache error log contains the exception:

```
AssertionError: The EvalException middleware is not usable in a multi-process environment
```

Here's my VHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  pyramidtest.dev
    DocumentRoot    /srv/pyramidtest.dev/www/
    AssignUserID    pyramidtest nogroup
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/pyramidtest.dev/pyramid/load.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's my `load.wsgi`:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/opt/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

from pyramid.paster import get_app

application = get_app('/srv/pyramidtest.dev/pyramid/test/development.ini', 'main')
```

mod_wsgi is compiled to use `/opt/python2.7` as the Python interpreter but I'm running Pyramid under a virtualenv in `/opt/pyramid` - This is why I have the `site.addsitedir()` in my load.wsgi.

And, in case it's needed, `apache2 -V`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
Server built:   Dec 30 2010 11:50:24
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:15
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.12, APR-Util 1.2.12
Compiled using: APR 1.2.12, APR-Util 1.2.12
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     ITK
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/experimental/itk"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT=""
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

What am I missing...?

Answer (score 6):

You're using the EvalException middleware (as can be seen from your error message). This solution to this error is actually covered in the [Debugging Techniques wiki](http://The%20EvalException%20middleware%20is%20not%20usable%20in%20a%20multi-process%20environment) of mod_wsgi.

Basically, since the middleware allows browser-based interactive debugging of your application, all requests need to be sent to the same process; however, you are running mod_wsgi in embedded mode, which can create many processes by default.

From the wiki:

> [...] if you want to be able to use this
>   browser based interactive debugger, if
>   running your application in embedded
>   mode of mod_wsgi, you will need to
>   configure Apache such that it only
>   starts up one child process to handle
>   requests and that it never creates any
>   additional processes. The Apache
>   configuration directives required to
>   achieve this are as follows.
>
> ```
> StartServers 1  
> ServerLimit 1
> ```

Switching to daemon mode (with a single process, the default) will also fix this problem, and is recommended over running in embedded mode. Here are the Apache directives:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramidtest.dev display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup pyramidtest.dev
```

mod_wsgi can also add the path to the Python path for you. If using embedded mode you can use:

```
WSGIPythonPath /opt/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If using daemon mode, instead use the 'python-path' option to the WSGIDaemonProcess directive.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramidtest.dev display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/opt/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup pyramidtest.dev
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I followed your advice and placed the `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup` directives into my VHost. The exception has now gone away but I'm getting this error in its place: `(13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=17417): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'pyramidtest.dev' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.17384.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.`

Comment: @jim: That's also covered in the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets) ;-) The UNIX socket file used to communicate doesn't have the right permissions since the default directory is locked down; you can specify a directory with the right permissions using the  `WSGISocketPrefix` directive. Read the wiki for suggestions on good socket paths ("run/wsgi" often works, apparently)

Comment: I've setup a `/var/log/wsgi/` directory and it's readable by all. I then added the WSGISocketPrefix to my `httpd.conf` (as it isn't allowed within vhosts) and it's still failing. I got those instructions from [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues)

Comment: @jim: It also has to be writeable for whatever user Apache is running as

Comment: It seems you were typing at the same time I was but beat me to the [enter]. As I was still getting the `permission denied` error, I tried changing the path to `/tmp/wsgi` but it's still occurring. The wsgi lock file is being owned by `www-data:root` and is only rwx by www-data. Is this right?

Comment: Again with the enter xD Apache is running as different users/groups for each vhost. I'm using `apache2-mpm-itk`. Is it only the directory that holds the wsgi lock that must be writable by that user? Or the lock itself? If it's the directory, I can just allow global writes to it... But if it's the lock, how can I set which user/group it's owned by or the permissions for it when created? :/

Comment: @jim: I think mod_wsgi will create the lock file with the appropriate permissions (though try setting it to `666` temporarily just in case), but the directory (socket prefix) has to have the correct permissions on it. I don't know Apache/mod_wsgi well enough to know which user should own the socket file/directory, but the wiki indicates it should be whoever Apache is running as (which makes sense if it's going to be reading and writing to the socket). I'm off to catch some sleep, it's late here :-) Good luck!

Comment: Given that I set `AssignUserID` in my vhost and I have the `WSGISocketPrefix` in my httpd.conf, it'd make sense why the lock owned by www-data. Apache doesn't su into the user (set in my vhost) until after the lock is created. I chmodded it 666 and then got an error in my errorlog showing a fopen() error on my `load.wsgi` file. I'm guessing this error is due to load.wsgi only being readable by the user set in my vhost. Not www-data. modwsgi and apache2-mpm-itk don't seem to play very nicely together >.<

Comment: Ok, if I add the user/group params to my `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive, it is able to read `load.wsgi` and the website runs. The only problem is I have to manually chmod the wsgi lock when I restart apache...

Comment: The ITK module is a special case from memory. What version of mod_wsgi are you using? You must use mod_wsgi 3.3 or later. What the newer version does is setup ownership/permissions so that the user that ITK process/daemon process runs as. See 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0303'.