# Can't Get Pyramid to Work with mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I have a Pyramid app and apache with mod_wsgi and I'm trying to make them work together. Here is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/home/user/webapps/myapp/apache2"
LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedCustomLog /home/user/logs/user/access_myapp.log combined
ErrorLog /home/user/logs/user/error_myapp.log
KeepAlive Off
Listen 41121   
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5   
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp processes=1 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs/lib/python2.4/site-packages/ threads=4

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs/pyramid.wsgi

<Directory /home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all    
</Directory>
```

Unfortunately, I get a server error: AssertionError: The EvalException middleware is not usable in a multi-process environment

I followed [this](http://www.kemeneur.com/clients/pylons/docs/pyramid/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html) tutorial and looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269447/trying-to-get-pyramid-running-under-apache-mod-wsgi-but-its-failing) post, but couldn't really make anything of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the 'processes=1' option from WSGIDaemonProcess. Ie., let it default to a single process and don't set it explicitly. Any use of 'processes' option will cause 'wsgi.multiprocess' to be set to True which isn't what you want. See documentation for 'processes' option in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

Answer (score 1):

You must disable debug mode in yours deployment settings