# Deploy pyramid/pylons application on shared hosting

Tags: python, apache, deployment, pylons, pyramid

I have a locally developed Pylons application. I also have hosting provider with SSH access, python 2.6 and have set a [virtual environment](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) on the server. After that using easy_install I have installed Pylons and achieved to execute it on port XXXX. The problem is that the firewall of the server is blocking any port other from 80 (the port of the Apache http). Can I redirect Apache to forward to my Pylons server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in jail or virtual container where running your isolate instance of apache, just kill it.
You can see process list  by execute 'top' utility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a virtualhost in apache so that it uses wsgi.

There's a plenty of topics in stackoverflow about this, such as

[Trying to get Pyramid running under Apache + mod_wsgi but it's failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269447/trying-to-get-pyramid-running-under-apache-mod-wsgi-but-its-failing)

(you can follow the link in the first sentence).

If you cannot use mod_wsgi, that you can try with mod_rewrite or mod_proxy, which have worse performance. If you cannot change the apache configuration, ask you provider, or start thinking about changing provider.